# Can't start application in IDE with <jar-find> error, but 'gradle bootRun' - works fine

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-boot

So, i have a problem that can't solve.
I have a multi module gradle project with spring boot runners. With Jpa, Elastic, OrientDb and another configurations provided by spring-data and spring-integration. And i try to start my web application! Write web starter, make annotation scan, so when I use task 'gradle bootRun' - everything start perfectly - app works, all contexts up and life is good.BUT, when i try use my favorite IDE like Intellij idea, or colleague use Eclipse - get an error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExce ption: Error creating bean with 
name 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGenerato rConfigurer#0': 
BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExce ption: Error creating bean with 
name org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lo rg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryV
```

That cause by (projectName - is fake):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>:
file:/home/<user>/project/<projectName>/classes/production/<projectName>-system-webapp/
```

**But i have NO** `/projectName/classes/production/` folder! Anyway - with gradle it's work fine.

And to be honestly, before this another error catched:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class com.project.system.jpa.PepperJpaConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed
caused by:

error trying to scan <jar-file>: file:/home/<user>/project/<projectName>/classes/production/<projectName>-system-webapp/
```

Thank you for advice! Can give additional info.

**P.S : Edited**

So, the problem was solved:
I do not provide important error stacktrace like:

```
at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getFilesInJar(NativeScanner.java:195)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:506)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:861)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18 at 50
```

And this was and JDK8-Hibernate-javassist problem https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8286
When upgrade javassist version to 3.18.1-GA - **all problems was solved**(but why run through gradle worked perfectly...)

Comment: Check your classpath? How did you create the IDE project metadata?

Comment: @DaveSyer I have configured **Project compile output** /home/user/project/projectName/classes In Intellij idea project settings. I try to generate classes through `gradle classes`, and run again - but the same result

Comment: but we can't see your persistence.xml (that has an entry about jar-file)

Comment: @NeilStockton I do not have any persistence.xml. Only java code and annotations driven configuration. For example - my entityManager: `@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.project");

        return lef;    
    }`